# Adding a dummy field

Tags: infopath

In infopath form I went to

> Field pane
>   Main is selected for data source
>   Right click on "myFields"
>   The add field adds column to the list.

I need to add a dummy field in Infopath for some calculation but this field dont need to be SharePoint List (which the form is associated with).

Comment: When I add a field in the main data source it adds it to the sp list but I just need a local field. Other data source wont let me create a field/column.

Comment: Reading this article http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2008/11/how-to-create-a-hidden-field-in-infopath/ in bullet 1 he talks about default setup for infopath. Now I dont remember whether I had this checked or unchecked during infopath installation. Is there a config file for infopath that I can customize?

Comment: I am giving up on this forum. Thought I could get some help but I was WRONG.

Comment: I'm assuming it's because you're customizing a list form in InfoPath and nnot creating a form in a form library as that sounds like the accurate way to do it.  Expecting an answer in an hour is a little unreasonable, cause you know, we have jobs too. You've asked one other question and gotten a response and an accepted answer, so the site does work.

Comment: @PirateEric: Actually that was a friend who personally emailed me the solution. And I asked her to post it here.